# List of study topics

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008

I have experience developing MFC applications with C++ using Visual Studio 6.0. You can guess how long ago that was (hint: going on 10 years).  I am trying to update my skills but a lot has changed.  How would one go about bringing these skills up to date?

Comment: depends on what you want to go into, what is your preference? language change? web framework?

Comment: Yeah, which skills do you want to bring up to date? C++? MFC? Windows development? Programming in general?

Comment: To all: I am humbled by your willingness to help others.  Thank you very much.  TStamper & jalf, your questions have helped direct my thoughts, thanks. For some reason, a third answer that referred to the tutorials no longer appears -- a very good resource.  Chris, thanks for the advice.  I've visited your blog as well.  Another great resource.  Confidence is a big issue in my case.  Thanks to sites like this and people like you all, the outlook is much brighter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in C++?  boost is definitely worth playing with.

C# is a good complimentary language.
WPF is a good MFC alternative.

There have also been improvements to MFC so you can create modern looking apps, worth looking at.  Still a number of people who create native code windows apps.

- pick up a scripting language of
  somesort, lua, python, ruby...
- pick up a functional language of somesort,
  haskell, F#, or something
- learn about ORMs
- Design Patterns
- TDD and Unit testing
- Refactoring

Answer (score 1):

I would learn about web development if I were you.  That is where a lot of jobs are going these days, it requires multiple skills, and will stretch your understanding of how software should be written (do to the stateless nature of the web).